# Elements of order $7$ and rational canonical forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

> The prime factorization of $x^7-1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ is
>
> $$x^7-1=(x-1)(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1).$$
>
> Recall that for any field $F$, a matrix $A \in Gl_n(F)$ satisfies $A^7=I$ (i.e., $A$ has order dividing $7$) if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^7-1$.
>
> a) Give the rational canonical forms of all elements of order exactly $7$ in $Gl_3(\Bbb{Z}_2)$. (Write down the specific $3 \times 3$ matrices).
>
> b) Give the rational canonical forms of all elements of order exactly $7$ in $Gl_6(\Bbb{Z}_2)$. Here you may use $C(f)$ notation and specify appropriate block sums for appropriate $f$'s.

a) Since any matrix satisfying $x-1$ has order 1, the other two are possible minimal polynomials for matrices of order $7$. But if a matrix satisfies $x^3+x^2+1$ or $x^3+x+1$, then it must be of order either $1$ or $7$. Since it can't be $1$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & -1 \\0 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

as the possible rational canonical forms.

b) We have

$$C(x^3+x^2+1) \oplus C(x^3+x^2+1)$$

$$C(x^3+x+1) \oplus C(x^3+x+1)$$

$$C(x^3+x+1) \oplus C(x^3+x^2+1)$$

Is that correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remember that since the characteristic is $2$, we have $1=-1$.

Comment: @MTurgeon Thanks. So is that just a suggestion that I should write 1 instead of -1, or do you mean that I'm missing something?

Comment: I mean the former

Comment: @MTurgeon So is my answer correct?